# d3.js: Multiple linechart plots on one page

Tags: javascript, d3.js

To clarify it I do not want a multi line chart. I want for example three charts with one line in each displayed on one page.

In my example I have a dataset like this:

```
signalData: {
  signal1: {
    name: "",
    data: {2,3,1,4,5,1,3},
  },
  signal2: {
    name: "",
    data: {2,3,1,4,5,1,3},
  },
  signal3: {
    name: "",
    data: {2,3,1,4,5,1,3},
  },
```

(Yes I already have a function which flattens the data and puts it into an array...)

I want 3 different linecharts which display the 3 different signals. But the function also has to be dynamic, because the amount of signals is variable and can be more or less!
Because of this fact static div's are not an option for me but I can append the svg's to the `body`.

I tried to visualize how I mean it:

[image]

Is there any way to do this. It would be nice if you could ad an example too (In best case with a linechart).

**My first idea was to split the process of generating a chart:**

1. Create and call a function which processes the data.
2. Create and call a function which draws the chart with the specific data as many times as I have `signals` in the `signalData` Object.

Is this an option and/or even possible in d3? If yes let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Just use the same logic you normally use to draw multiple lines/bars/points/labels/anything really, and apply it to charts. Move the logic to create a chart in the function `draw` and it should draw three separate line charts.

Note that I've changed your data type from a key-value pair to an array though, because those are easier to handle in d3. It's not necessary, but a convenience. Otherwise, just iterate over the key-value pairs using `Object.keys(signalData)` to get the array `["signal1", "signal2", "signal3"]` and access the underlying data as `signalData[myKey]`

```js
const signalData = [
  {
    name: "Signal 1",
    data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
  },
  {
    name: "Signal 2",
    data: [2,3,1,4,5,1,3],
  },
  {
    name: "Signal 3",
    data: [1,7,2,6,3,5,4],
  },
];

// This is a line generator. Normally, you pass the x- and y-scales in,
// see also d3-scale on github
const line = d3.line()
  // The first argument is always the datum object, the second is the index
  // Note that I use the index to determine the x coordinate of each point here
  .x((d, i) => i * 50)
  // And the datum object for the y-coordinate
  .y(d => 150 - (15 * d));
  
// The term `datum` is unrelated to date, but is the singular value of `data`.
// One datum, many data.

d3.select("body")
  .selectAll("svg")
  // Append one svg per array entry, look up the so-called enter, update, exit
  // cycle for this. It's the most complex part of d3
  .data(signalData)
  .enter()
  .append("svg")
  // Execute a custom function for each element. People who are new to d3.js
  // over-use this function, very often you don't need it!
  .each(function(d, i) {
    // I pass the current svg element, the datum object, and the index for convenience
    draw(d3.select(this), d, i);
  });

function draw(svg, data, index) {
  // Append a label, set the text to the name
  svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", 20)
    .attr("y", 20)
    .text(d => d.name);
  
  // Append a path, take the datum of the svg, pick it's `data` property,
  // which is the array of numbers, and set that as the datum of the path,
  // then call the line generator
  svg.append("path")
    .datum(d => d.data)
    .attr("d", line);
}
```

```css
path {
  stroke: darkblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  fill: none;
}

svg {
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 2px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224247/discussion-between-ruben-helsloot-and-felix-waigner).

Comment: I found another solution would love to hear you opinion about that. Maybe open chat again?